# How do you configure a DataSource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am studying for Spring Core certification and I have some doubt about how correctly answer to this question:

> How do you configure a DataSource in Spring? Which bean is very useful
>   for development?

I think that I do something like this to configure **DataSource** in a Spring XML configuration file:

```
<bean id=“dataSource” class=“org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource”>
    <property name=“url” value=“${dataSource.url}” />
    <property name=“username” value=“${dataSource.username}” />
    <property name=“password” value=“${dataSource.password}” />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source=“dataSource”>
    <jdbc:script location=“classpath:schema.sql” />
    <jdbc:script location=“classpath:test-data.sql” />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

So I think that the answered bean is the **org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource**. Is this assertion true or am I missing something?

What exactly represent the declared  configuration tag? It is clear for me what it do but what exactly represent? Is it a special bean declaration or what?

Tnx

Comment: "Which bean is very useful for development?" They all are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it has to be helper for creating in memory DB for DEV purposes:

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public DataSource devDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql")
        .build();
}
```

XML config:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Relevant part of [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-embedded-database-support).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about  exams and certification questions :-) 
But here is a valid XML datasource config JDBC MySQL

```
    <!-- App's dataSource used by jdbcTemplate,jdbc-user-service and connectController anss so on -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springappdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="yourpassword" />
</bean>

<!-- jdbcTemplate --> 
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: DriverManagerDataSource doesn't provide pooling, use for testing purposes only. straight from the docs.